# Active directory nods could not get domain controller name

Tags: active-directory

I have two nodes in my Active Directory, node1.ds.exmaple.com and node2.ds.example.com. I run the following command on each of these nodes:

```
Test-cluster -node node1.ds.exmaple.com,node2.ds.example.com
```

When I check the report, on **node1** I get:

```
Connectivity to a writable domain controller from node node2.ds.example.com could not be determined because of this error: Could not get domain controller name from machine node2.

Node(s) node1.ds.example.com can reach a writable domain controller.

Node(s) node2.ds.example.com cannot reach a writable domain controller. Please check connectivity of these nodes to the domain controllers.
```

When I check the report, on **node2** I get:

```
Connectivity to a writable domain controller from node node1.ds.example.com could not be determined because of this error: Could not get domain controller name from machine node1.

Node(s) node2.ds.example.com can reach a writable domain controller.

Node(s) node1.ds.example.com cannot reach a writable domain controller. Please check connectivity of these nodes to the domain controllers.
```

Can someone please help me understand why the nodes are not able to get the domain controller name?

Comment: can both nodes resolve the dns names?

Comment: both the nodes can resolve `node1.ds.example.com`, `node2.ds.example.com` and `ds.example.com`

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/751428/could-not-get-domain-controller-name-from-machine

Comment: `Can someone please help me understand why the nodes are not able to get the domain controller name?` - It could literally be anything. Start with looking at the DNS configuration on the nodes and the DC. Then look at the network test results in the cluster validation report.

Comment: @Sum1sAdmin I already had a look at that. I am not running the validation from DC and DNS tests are passing for me.

Comment: @joeqwerty the DNS config looks good and I can use nslookup to verify. the network test results do not have any error. Only the active directory section has errors which I have mentioned above

Comment: Have you installed the cluster role on the domain controllers? DC's do not need cluster role to provide redundancy. Are the cluster nodes in different AD sites? https://support.microsoft.com/fil-ph/help/4025260/cluster-validation-test-fails-for-multi-site-cluster

Comment: I am not sure why this failed, however in my case it was resolved by restarting netlogon service on the node that failed the test. Maybe also related with network configuration / dns suffix (?)

Answer (score 0):

When you start a cluster validation test on a node, the node selects a domain controller to be used for the test. During the Active Directory configuration validation, all computers that are selected as part of the validation are pointed to use this domain controller. In a multi-site cluster scenario, the network communications may be designed in way where computers are only allowed to communicate with domain controllers that are in their local site. Therefore, these computers are prevented from communications with remote domain controllers. In this scenario, computers in other sites are not able to communicate with the selected domain controller which leads to the failure of the cluster validation test.

If the computers can communicate to a domain controller in the domain, and the domain controllers are successfully replicating, then the functionality of your failover cluster is not impacted.

In a multi-site cluster scenario, you can safely ignore the failed validation. Meanwhile, your failover cluster is still supported by Microsoft Technical Support.